# How to pass this props to functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

First of all I rarely use functional component, but this time I required to use it. **So, I have this component called Login that use redux :**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getLoginData } from "../../redux/actions/LoginActions";

function Login() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { getLoginData } = this.props;
    getLoginData("test");
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  login: state.login,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getLoginData: (value) => dispatch(getLoginData(value)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

It produce error since `this` is undefined. **But, if I change it to class component like this:**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getLoginData } from "../../redux/actions/LoginActions";

class Login extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getLoginData } = this.props;
    getLoginData("test");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  login: state.login,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getLoginData: (value) => dispatch(getLoginData(value)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

It will worked as expected(the redux is also worked). **The question is, How can I pass `this.props` to functional component?**

Comment: In a functional component you do not have to bind props with this

Comment: this is not available in functional component.

Comment: @All Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the silly question, I just stuck from yesterday haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function components get their props passed in as the argument to that function:

```
function Login(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getLoginData("test");
  }, []);
  // ...
}

// Or with destructuring:
function Login({ login, getLoginData }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getLoginData("test");
  }, []);
  // ...
}
```

That said, if you're using a function component, then it's simpler to [use hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) instead of connect:

```
function Login() {
  const login = useSelector(state => state.login);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLoginData("test"));
  }, []);
  //...
}

// Note that there is no mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps/connect here
export default Login;
```

Comment: ooww, okay. I use connect because I following the redux on class component. hanks for the answer and the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), you pass a `props` object to the function and access the values as attributes of `props`.

So, for your implementation, you'd do it like this:

```
function Login(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getLoginData("test");
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or, you could replace `function Login(props)` with `function Login({getLoginData})` to unwrap the value and replace `props.getLoginData("test")` with `getLoginData("test")`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I just missed the docs about functional component